# DiscordJS: Determine reaction was removed by a human

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, discord.js, dom-events

I have a discord bot that when when a certain number of reactions received, it stops any more users from reacting. This is the event listener that does that:

```
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

  if (
    reaction.emoji.name === "️‍♂️" &&
    reaction.message.author.bot &&
    user.id !== "773710233977618464"
  ) {
    const spotsLeft = reaction.message.embeds[0].fields[1].value;

    if (spotsLeft == 0) {
      return reaction.users.remove(user.id);
    }
...
}
```

However, this is triggering my `MessageReactionRemove` event later, which I do not want triggered. I have tried to filter that out with the following:

```
bot.on("messageReactionRemove", (reaction, user) => {
  if (
    reaction.emoji.name === "️‍♂️" &&
    reaction.message.author.bot &&
    user.id !== "773710233977618464"
  ) {
...
```

I have tried !user.bot and several other things, but every time I console log from what I can tell it looks like the reaction removal is coming from a user. I `console.log(user.id)` and it is the person whose reaction was removed ID.

How do I tell DiscordJS "if this is triggered by Javascript or a bot, do nothing"?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by enabling the partials "USER", "GUILD_MEMBER" and "REACTIONS". Additional reading here: [enter link description here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials)